Are the epistles of the New Testament the word of God?
The Apostle Paul said, "All Scripture is inspired by God and is profitable for teaching, for rebuking, for correcting, for training in righteousness, so that the man of God may be complete, equipped for every good work." (2 Tim 3:16-17 HCSB) Now, I am aware of the canonization of the New Testament. This was done some 300 plus years after these letters were written. Now, some of these letters do contain scripture references in them but to call them the word of God. I don't think that was the intent of the writers.
Why do scholars today say that the whole Bible is the word of God?

When Paul affirmed the inspiration of the scriptures in 2 Timothy 3:16-17, he was referring to the already settled collection of Hebrew scriptures that all Jews had, and were familiar with (and which had also been translated into Greek). That is why he commended the Bereans for checking out what he claimed against the inspired scriptures available to them (what we call the Old Testament today.)
That's in Acts 17:11. He called them noble-minded for not just taking his word for things. The gospel of Christ he preached had to accord with what was already known to be God's word. But bear in mind that the letter called "The Acts" had not been completed when that bit about the Bereans was written. The Bereans did not have any documents about the acts of the apostles. Even after it was finished, hand-written copies of it would have to be made and then distributed to the many congregations of Christians. Same with all the parts of what we now call the New Testament. The last book of that was completed almost at the end of the first century.
However, Peter wrote in his second letter about Paul's epistles:

"And account that the longsuffering of our Lord is salvation; even as
our beloved brother Paul also according to the wisdom given unto him
hath written unto you. As also in all his epistles, speaking in them
of these things; in which are some things hard to be understood, which
they that are unlearned and unstable wrest, as they do also the other
scriptures, unto their own destruction." 2 Peter 3:15-16 K.J.V.

See how Peter categorizes Paul's epistles with "the other scriptures"?
As for how the early Christians viewed all the New Testament gospels and epistles, they had no problems with accepting all of them. It was only a bit later on that other writings had to be considered, as to whether they were also holy scripture, or not. Some claimed to be that, but were studied and declared not to be so. No council of Christian leaders ever met to decide which writings should form the New Testament. It's an urban myth that the AD 325 Council of Nicea did. It wasn't until AD 367 that Athanasius of Alexandria produced a formal list of the 27 NT writings that are accepted even till today. Regional councils in Hippo (AD 393) and Carthage (AD 397) simply affirmed his list. Such a canonical list settled the matter and it was based on whether any writing was inspired of God, which would mean it had to be true to the testimony of Christ as recorded by the apostles and eye witnesses.
But Christians of the first century began to get either the originals, or copies of all 27 'books' of what we now call the New Testament, and they accepted them. Confirmation of them as cannonical, plus exclusion of other writings that were not inspired of God, took much longer to be finally settled, but all of Paul's epistles were accepted, from the start, as equally inspired of God as the four gospel accounts.
http://www.gotquestions.org/canon-Bible.html

"It's an urban myth that the AD 325 Council of Nicea did. It wasn't until AD 367 that Athanasius of Alexandria produced a formal list of the 27 NT writings "  Maybe not a myth, but something that isn't well documented exactly.  See 50 bibles of Constantine.  And note comment: "Athanasius of Alexandria referred to another request of producing Bible manuscripts: "I sent to him volumes containing the holy Scriptures, which he had ordered me to prepare for him."[6][7] Athanasius could have received this request between 337 and 339".  IOW, it may have been that the NT was codified much earlier.

@SLM  Yes, the commission of Constantine for 50 Bibles to be copied is an excellent point. And your other points. Thanks!

Some trace the NT from John and Paul (getting the separate books together) to Polycarp (whose letter mentions all (some say, but clearly nearly all) of the books of the NT).  Not everyone agreed with what actually became the NT, so it appears to us that the codification came some 300 years after the last apostle (John son of Zebedee, of the sons of thunder) passed.  Just food for thought---would God really have left it up to people?  See answer from Nephesh.

In all my years of studying the Bible and following Jesus I have never viewed all the books of the bible in it's entirety the word of God. Jesus always referenced back to the word of the Lord, "It is written" or "you have heard". Even being the Son of God, he always said that the words he was speaking weren't his own but they were the words given to him by his father. Thus, making these words. The Word of God! Which clearly helps me understand how John could write, "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God." (John 1:1) This passage never led me to think of Jesus being God but only guided me to understand that Jesus contained the very words of God in himself. Thus, "The Word became flesh and took up residence among us. We observed His glory, the glory as the One and Only Son from the Father" (John 1:14) Jesus' statements, "it is written" Matthew chapter 4 and "you have heard" chapter 5 led me to understand how the word became flesh and where the word of God was.
David, in his writings in the psalms says, "The entirety of Your word is truth, and all Your righteous judgments endure forever." (Psalm 119:160)Thus, not even David's words were the word of God. Here is a better way of putting into perspective. The traditional Jewish position is that the Torah is all divine in origin. Yet nowhere does the broader Bible suggest that it was all written by God and in no way is this belief necessary to live as an observant Jew. The Jewish Bible, the Tanach, attributes authorship of some of its sections to God, but these are few and far between.
Let’s start with the second part of the Jewish canon, the Prophets (Nevi’im). The early prophets — the Books of Joshua, Judges, Samuel, and Kings — claim to tell the history of Israel from the time of the conquest of the land after the Exodus through the destruction of the First Temple in 586 BCE. Nothing in the style of these books suggests that they are divine in origin. Though in places they certainly talk about God (in the third person), they present many different perspectives on this era and share all the pitfalls of humanly written histories
Some of the later prophets — Isaiah, Jeremiah, Ezekiel and the twelve minor prophets — explicitly claim to reflect divine revelation. The second verse of the Book of Jeremiah states that “the word of the LORD came to him [Jeremiah] in the days of [King] Josiah …” In case this is not definitive enough, the first real prophecy in the book opens: “The word of the LORD came to me.” (Jeremiah 1:4) Several other prophetic books contain similar claims, though not all. Isaiah simply begins: “The prophecies of Isaiah son of Amoz, who prophesied concerning Judah and Jerusalem in the reigns of…” (Isaiah 1:1). The book makes no explicit assertion of divine origin, though this was surely assumed by his audience.
Most of the books of the Writings (Ketuvim), the third section of the Tanach, completely lack the suggestion that they are from God. Psalms is a book of prayers to God, not from God (though some early Jews considered it divinely inspired). In most of the Book of Job, God is spoken of in the third person. Proverbs is mostly human wisdom. The five Megillot (scrolls) also lack any suggestion of divine authorship. Song of Songs, for example, is explicitly attributed to Solomon, with no hint of divine inspiration.  Only some sections of Daniel contain prophecies attributed to God—though unlike earlier prophecy, these are mediated by an angel.
(From Marc Zvi Brettler, https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/did-god-write-the-torah-and-does-it-matter/)
The epistles are not only Paul's letter but letters written from several different authors. Traditionally, they are shared experiences that these chosen men had with Jesus. Thus, the statements from Paul, Peter, James, Jude and John are not the word of God. Paul says, "For the message of the cross is foolishness to those who are perishing, but it is God’s power to us who are being saved. For it is written: I will destroy the wisdom of the wise, and I will set aside the understanding of the experts." (1 Cor.1:18-19) Then he goes on to say, "But it is from Him that you are in Christ Jesus, who became God-given wisdom for us—our righteousness, sanctification, and redemption, in order that, as it is written: The one who boasts must boast in the Lord." (1 Cor.1:30-31) We clearly see Paul's use of the word of God spoken through the prophets.

You cover a lot of ground in answering you own question. WRT Judaism and the OT anyone who rejects Jesus as the Christ does not correctly understand Scripture or the Word of God. WRT to the NT I think those who believe something like a letter identified as from Paul is not from Paul are denying it is from God and devoid of inspiration.

Good to know, if you believe it's inspired. My point is man doesn't get to pick and choose what is inspired. If one is not all in,  then one denies the Word.

To expand upon Anne's great answer, one should note that the writer of Peter was not actually Peter, but rather an anonymous Christian from the second century. There is no 'proof' that all of what is compiled today in the modern Bible is the word of God. No one knows if Paul and the other writers of his epistles believed or expected their writings to be the Word. The point of faith is that there is no proof. In other words, scholars today who say the complete Bible is the word of God say so because they believe it.
If I may expand beyond answering the question as posed, I would note that believing in Jesus Christ's teachings on their own merit, rather than propping them up on a belief in infallible scripture (and compilation, and translation, etc.), may be a more genuine faith in Him.

Regarding your last paragraph, are you including in that a belief that they are the teachings of Jesus himself, and not a fabrication? If so there’s some core faith there in faithful transmission of at least that part of Scripture. Also note that the teachings of Jesus aren’t in any way self-contained; they depend on the rest of Scripture.

Ok good to hear that—I’ve met some people who reject the authenticity of the Scriptures whole cloth but then “follow Jesus’ teachings” which doesn’t make a lot of sense to me and demonstrates that they are not in fact following Jesus’ teachings or they’d have accepted the whole word of God.

Could you point out to me where in Jesus's teaching he indicates that there will be future Scripture written after his teaching that we are to accept unquestionably on the same basis as Scripture? I'm not sure why someone can't just read Jesus's teachings and then decide to follow them. Isn't that more faithful than pinning everything on the unquestionable veracity of all of the writing that came after Jesus?

That’s a good question. Offhand this passage (John 16:12-14) comes to mind. It doesn’t specifically say they will be written down but it does call them Jesus’ words then-as-yet-unspoken:  12“I still have many things to say to you, but you cannot bear them now. 13When the Spirit of truth comes, he will guide you into all the truth, for he will not speak on his own authority, but whatever he hears he will speak, and he will declare to you the things that are to come. 14He will glorify me, for he will take what is mine and declare it to you.”

Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, and I find that passage too ambiguous to be extraordinary evidence. John was written much later than the other Gospels, ~89-95 AD. It makes sense to conclude that John contains post hoc quotes by Jesus. To me, it is enlightening to approach the New Testament as a collection of archeological evidence from which one can draw their own conclusions about who Jesus was and what he taught. Assuming all of it is Word of God, period, precludes critical thinking and leads to dogma (my interpretation of Truth is the real Truth, not yours).
